# String.Contains and String.LastIndexOf C# return different result?

Tags: c#, contains, lastindexof

I have this problem where String.Contains returns true and String.LastIndexOf returns -1. Could someone explain to me what happened? I am using .NET 4.5.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String wikiPageUrl = @"http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/ʿAbd_Allāh_al-Sallāl";

        if (wikiPageUrl.Contains("wikipedia.org/wiki/"))
        {

            int i = wikiPageUrl.LastIndexOf("wikipedia.org/wiki/");

            Console.WriteLine(i);

        }
    }
```

Comment: If that's a direct C&P then it doesn't compile. If it isn't a direct C&P: why not?

Comment: It returns 10 for me, as expected ([demo](http://ideone.com/qYl3sZ)). Voting to close as non-reproducible.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. I think quotes you are using are Unicode characters.

Comment: You have a typo: int i = wikiPageUrl.LastIndexOf **((** “wikipedia.org/wiki/” **)**;

Comment: @Dima, what about the quotes and missing semi-colon?

Comment: The LastIndexOf(String) method always returns String.Length – 1, which represents the last index position in the current instance.

Comment: @HassanNisar they're missing as well evidently :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `StringComparison.Ordinal`

This will compare the `string` by evaluating the numeric values of the corresponding `chars` in each `string`, this should work with the special `chars` you have in that example `string`

```
 string wikiPageUrl = @"http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/ʿAbd_Allāh_al-Sallāl";
 int i = wikiPageUrl.LastIndexOf("http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

// returns 0;

Answer (score 5):

While [@sa_ddam213's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614552/497356) definitely fixes the problem, it might help to understand exactly what's going on with this particular string.

If you try the example with other "special characters," the problem isn't exhibited. For example, the following strings work as expected:

```
string url1 = @"http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/»Abd_Allāh_al-Sallāl";
Console.WriteLine(url1.LastIndexOf("it.wikipedia.org/wiki/")); // 7

string url2 = @"http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/~Abd_Allāh_al-Sallāl";
Console.WriteLine(url2.LastIndexOf("it.wikipedia.org/wiki/")); // 7
```

The character in question, "ʿ", is called a [*spacing modifier letter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters)<sup>1</sup>. A spacing modifier letter doesn't stand on its own, but modifies the *previous* character in the string, this case a "/". Another way to put this is that it doesn't take up its own space when rendered.

`LastIndexOf`, when called with no `StringComparison` argument, compares strings using the current culture.

When strings are compared in a culture-sensitive manner, the "/" and "ʿ" characters are not seen as two distinct characters--they're processed into one character, which *does not match* the parameter passed in to `LastIndexOf`.

When you pass in `StringComparison.Ordinal` to `LastIndexOf`, the characters are treated as distinct, due to the nature of Ordinal comparison.

Another way to make this work would be to use `CompareInfo.LastIndexOf` and supply the `CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace` option:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.LastIndexOf(
        wikiPageUrl, @"it.wikipedia.org/wiki/", CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace));
// 7
```

Here we're saying that we don't want combining characters included in our string comparison.

As a sidenote, this means that [@Partha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614510/497356) and [@Noctis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614473/497356) only work because the character is being applied to a character that doesn't appear in the search string that's passed to `LastIndexOf`.

Contrast this with the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which by default performs an Ordinal (case sensitive and culture *in*sensitive) comparison. This explains why `Contains` returns `true` and `LastIndexOf` returns `false`.

For a fantastic overview of how strings should be manipulated in the .NET framework, check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

<sup>1</sup>: Is this different than a *combining character* or is it a type of combining character? would appreciate if someone would clear that up for me.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is C# lastindexof looks from behind.

And `wikipedia.org/wiki/` is followed by `'` which it takes as escape sequence. So either remove `'` after `wiki/` or have an `@` there too.

The following syntax will work( anyone )

```
string wikiPageUrl = @"http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd_Allāh_al-Sallāl";

string wikiPageUrl = @"http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/@ʿAbd_Allāh_al-Sallāl";

int i = wikiPageUrl.LastIndexOf("wikipedia.org/wiki");
```

All 3 works

If you want a generalized solution for this problem replace `'` with `@'` in your string before you perform any operations.

Answer (score 0):

the `'` characters throws it off.

This should work, when you escape the `'` as `\'`:

```
wikiPageUrl = @"http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/\'Abd_Allāh_al-Sallāl";

if (wikiPageUrl.Contains("wikipedia.org/wiki/"))
{
    "contains".Dump();
  int i = wikiPageUrl.LastIndexOf("wikipedia.org/wiki/");

  Console.WriteLine(i);

}
```

figure out what you want to do (remove the `'`, escape it, or dig deeper :) ).

Comment: I am running the job on entire Wikipedia and the column wikiPageUrl came from the database which I do not want to preprocess. I have some work around already but I want to know the reason why Contains return "true" and LastIndexOf returns "-1"